Getting a compiler error trying to write a complicated Predicate
I know there are similar questions out there, like this one for example Combining Predicate in SwiftData but all that looks unnecessary complex to me and I find it difficult to believe that there is no easier way.
This is what I need:
let aPred = #Predicate<Event> {
            $0.dateStart != nil &&
            ($0.dateStart >= startOfDay && $0.dateStart <= endOfDay) ||
            ($0.dateEnd >= startOfDay && $0.dateEnd <= endOfDay) ||
            ($0.dateStart < startOfDay && $0.dateEnd >= startOfDay)
}

Event is a SwiftData model which has 2 optional date properties dateStart and dateEnd which I need to compare against 2 dates startOfDay and endOfDay
You probably know that this will give a compiling error:

The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions.

In Core Data we could easily do this with a single NSPredicate like this:
let nsPred = NSPredicate(format: "dateStart != nil && (dateStart >= %@ && dateStart <= %@) || (dateEnd >= %@ && dateEnd <= %@) || (dateStart < %@ && dateEnd >= %@)",
                                argumentArray: [startOfDay, endOfDay,
                                                startOfDay, endOfDay,
                                                startOfDay, startOfDay])

Or if needed, we could break that down into smaller predicates and then use NSCompoundPredicate with .and or .or
There should be a simple way of achieving the same in SwiftData without all those complex macros, queries and predicate xpressions.
I have to keep each item optional as this is required by CloudKit.
Uploaded minimal working project here. See ViewController.swift.

The title of the question is made up of two framework names and one macro name and nothing else. Please make an effort to write a proper title

One possible improvement is to unwrap dateStart using if let

@MojtabaHosseini added link to the description.

The issue
This is because you are comparing an Optional<Date> against a Date.

The solution
Try to get rid of the optionality somehow like extending the Optional, so it can be compared:
extension Optional: Comparable where Wrapped: Comparable {
    public static func < (lhs: Wrapped?, rhs: Wrapped?) -> Bool {
        guard let lhs, let rhs else { return false }
        return lhs < rhs
    }
}

 Here is a working demo with optional predicate 

I have to keep each item optional as this is required by CloudKit

Unfortunately Method 1 is not possible, as it is a valid scenario to have a nil value. Can you please elaborate more on Method 2, not sure how to implement it @MojtabaHosseini

You can just copy this code below a file, so that your original code will compile. Because it makes the Date? types comparable. @grep

I must admit I do not understand this piece of code but it works. Marking your answer as accepted. Thank you. However, if try to add one more condition such as check against optional Bool $0.isActive == true I again get the same error, any chance you could help with that too?

As a quick description, it says: make anything you CAN compare originally, comparable if they are represented as an optional but NOT nil. I hope it helps.

And about the $0.isActive == true, it should not have a problem by itself. It seems there is another issue with the code. I have updated the sample code on the git to contain a Bool? but if you don't get it, try asking a new question with more  descriptive detail and link it here so that I can take a look.

@MojtabaHosseini posted a new question. Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78450900/getting-a-compiler-error-trying-to-write-a-complicated-predicate-scenario-2
